# Невежа - невежественный. Невежда - невеждественный?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

**Невежа** - производные от него - **невежественный, невежественно**.
А у **невежды** как?

Answer (score 2):

Все эти слова родственные, но если говорить о значении, то *невежественный* — это и есть необразованный, несведущий, соответсвующий существительному *невежда*. А вот *невежа* ближе к *невежливому*.

Answer (score 1):

Я хотел бы дополнить исторической справкой. До начала 19 века слова "невежа" и "невежда" употреблялись в одном значении - "неученый", "необразованный".

> Подлый и благородный, богатый и убогий, ученый и невежа, мужественный
>   и боязливый, все единым образом раждаются... архиеп. Платон (Левшин),
>   1764

Только в середине 19 века произошел перенос понятия в слове невежа (неученый > необразованный > грубый, невежливый)

> "...невежа, милостивый государь, тот, кто позволяет себе грубость". Л.
>   Толстой, Юность, 1857

В результате трудно сказать, что от чего произведено.

Answer (score 0):

От *невежды* - **неведущий**. Здесь мы видим чередование согласных в корне.